# placing the taskbar

Tags: taskbar

I successfully installed U13.04x64 at first attempt.
then I tried to move the taskbar to the bottom of the screen - to no avail.
I twisted and turned but couldn't do it for my life, and ended up uninstalling U and installing Mint.
was I chasing a ghost ?
thanks,
RC

Answer (score 0):

Yes the taskbar or rather "Launcher" doesn't move.